# curl use: codification of "&" in web parameters

Tags: curl

I am having problems to get the following url with curl (in chrome works perfectly)

```
curl --user "user:pass" -v http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/incomeStatement/detail?stmtType=INC'&'perType=INT'&'symbol=GG
```

Any clue?

Comment: Instead of just the & put the entire url between single quotes or so ``curl --user "user:pass" -v 'http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/incomeStatement/detail?stmtType=INC&perType=INT&symbol=GG'``

Comment: Yes, now it works (the command is proccesed). Now the problem is that I can not loggin. The web doesn't recognize the --user command.

Comment: Not sure what 'The web doesn't recognize the --user command.' means.

Answer (score 1):

1. Surround your URL with `'` marks:

   ```
   curl --user "user:pass" -v 'http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/incomeStatement/detail?stmtType=INC&perType=INT&symbol=GG'
   ```
2. Surround your URL with `"` marks:

   ```
   curl --user "user:pass" -v "http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/incomeStatement/detail?stmtType=INC&perType=INT&symbol=GG"
   ```
3. Escape the `&` characters:

   ```
   curl --user "user:pass" -v http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/incomeStatement/detail?stmtType=INC\&perType=INT\&symbol=GG
   ```